# sketch a interval

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In general, how do you do when you sketching a interval? I know how to sketch a function $y=x+1$ for example, then I just have some inputs for example:

for $y=2$ gives $x=1$, and then just plot it out in a graph.

but how do you do that when it comes to interval like this: $1 \le x^2 \le 2$ ?
and if we have $1 \le x^2 + y \le 2$

Answer (score 0):

$\{x: 1 \leq x^{2} \leq 2\}=[1,\sqrt 2] \cup [-\sqrt 2, -1]$.

$y=1-x^{2}$ and $y=2-x^{2}$ are parabolas with vertices  $(0,1)$ and $(0,2)$ and axes along the $y-$ axis and $\{1\leq x^{2}+y \leq 2\}$ is the region between these two parabolas.

Comment: That is more complicated. $x^{2}y=1$ is something like a hyperbola. You have to sketch enough points on it to see how it looks like. You should  also sketch $x^{2}y=2$ and then mark the points between these two curves.  @sannahoho13

Comment: @sannahoho13 Yes, exactly.